# Sublime Text (PC) - Keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, sublimetext2, shortcut

I am new in Sublime Text.

How do I select all occurrences in text file?
I am a PC user. I know by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> you can select the next occurrence, and by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> multiple times you can select more. But how do you select everything at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a cursor at all occurrences on Windows, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or, on a Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Here is a nice collection of Sublime features: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

first you select the term then press ctrl+f, finaly press the button(find all) to the right of the